# How can I call a function as I type in an Android EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Here's my scenario. I want to integrate into an EditText a search function. But I don't want it to be an external button, I want to call that function as I type in the EditBox.

How can I achieve this ? Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a `TextWatcher` for your `EditText`. The three callbacks are called when the text, in the attached `EditText` changes

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

you can find more details on the documentation, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html), It is an editable text vview that shows completion suggestions as the user types.

```
 public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.countries);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can implement a textwatcher for your editbox and in onTextChanged event first see do u have minimum number of characters entered e.g. 3 if length of input is greater than or equal to 3 start a timer which will execute after 2 seconds. But if you again get onTextChanged cancel and purge the previous timer and set it again. Something like this:

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.length() >= 3){
            scheduleTimer(); //Reschedule timer.
        }else{
            cancelTimer(); //cancel scheduled timer
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
  };
```

Set the textwatcher to your edittext.

```
et_search_box.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Method for scheduling a timer

```
Timer searchScheduleTimer = null;
private void scheduleTimer(){
    cancelTimer();
    searchScheduleTimer = new Timer("search_scheduler");
    searchScheduleTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

             @Override
             public void run() {
               //do your processing here.
             }
           });
       }
    }, 1500);
}
```

Method for cancelling scheduled timer.

```
private void cancelTimer(){
    if (searchScheduleTimer != null){
        searchScheduleTimer.cancel();
        searchScheduleTimer.purge();
        searchScheduleTimer = null;
    }
}
```